# fetch records of last 90 days from current date in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Hi am using below query to retrieve records last 90 days from current date but its not working. please help me.

```
SELECT * 
FROM adhoc_request 
WHERE DATEDIFF(("d", Crdate, current_date()) < 90);
```

Answer (score 10):

```
SELECT * 
FROM adhoc_request 
WHERE Crdate >= sysdate-90
```

[SYSDATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm) includes the time portion, e.g. "04-13-2013 09:45:51"

So in effect, the query run on "04-13-2013 09:45:51" translates to

```
WHERE Crdate >= "2013-01-13 09:45:51"
```

David's suggestion works more predictably and is in most cases more correct, which first truncates SYSDATE to return just today's date before taking 90 days off it, i.e.

```
SELECT * 
FROM adhoc_request 
WHERE Crdate >= TRUNC(sysdate)-90
```

Comment: And consider using trunc(sysdate)-90 if you only want to consider complete days.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below query for oracle

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    adhoc_request 
WHERE 
    trunc(sysdate-Crdate)<90
```

Comment: hi wen i try to execute this query im getting the below error

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from adhoc_request
where Crdate < DATEADD("d", -90, current_date()) < 90);
```

Some notes:

- Never use a function on a predicate in a WHERE clause. Note CrDate is alone in my code
- DATEADD will extract exactly 90 days including time. DATEDIFF counts midnight boundaries

Comment: DATEADD is not available in Oracle - the SQL tag does *not* indicate a question for SQL server.

Comment: Sorry if my comment offended you - but DATEADD() *is* a SQL server function (whereas CURRENT_DATE apparently is MySQL), so I assumed your solution was SQL server only.

Comment: I did think MySQL but MySQL uses DATE_ADD. I didn't check syntax. I get mixed up between dialects sometimes

Answer (score 0):

```
 Where trunc(Crdate) BETWEEN (trunc(sysdate)-INTERVAL '90' DAY) AND trunc(sysdate)
```